# Coalescing multiple chunks of columns with the same suffix in names (R)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataset with various "chunks" of columns with different prefixes, but the same suffix:

| ID | A034 | B034 | C034 | D034 | A099 | B099 | A123 | B123 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NA | 1 | NA | NA | NA | 3 | 1 | NA | ... |
| 2 | 2 | NA | NA | NA | 2 | NA | NA | 2 | ... |
| 3 | NA | NA | 2 | NA | NA | 2 | 1 | NA | ... |

The number of columns within each "chunk" also varies.  Is there any way (other than manually, which is what I have been painstakingly doing with `coalesce(!!! select(., contains("XXX")))`)  to automatically coalesce by chunk based on the shared suffix? That is, the result should resemble

| ID | 034 | 099 | 123 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 1 | ... |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | ... |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | 1 | ... |

I'm not sure how to begin doing something like this, so any suggestions would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We reshape the data into 'long' format with [`pivot_longer`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html), then we group by 'ID' and loop `across` the other columns, apply the `na.omit` to remove the NA elements (we assume that there is only one non-NA per each column by group)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -ID, names_to = ".value", 
           names_pattern = "[A-Z](\\d+)") %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>%
    summarise(across(everything(), na.omit), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
     ID `034` `099` `123`
  <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     1     3     1
2     2     2     2     2
3     3     2     2     1
```

---

Or to be safe, use `complete.cases` to create a logical vector for non-NA elements, and extract the first element (assuming we need only a single non-NA - if the non-NA lengths are different, we may need to return a `list`)

```
df1 %>%
     pivot_longer(cols = -ID, names_to = ".value",
          names_pattern = "[A-Z](\\d+)") %>%
     group_by(ID) %>% 
     summarise(across(everything(),  ~ .[complete.cases(.)][1]))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, A034 = c(NA, 2L, NA), B034 = c(1L, NA, 
NA), C034 = c(NA, NA, 2L), D034 = c(NA, NA, NA), A099 = c(NA, 
2L, NA), B099 = c(3L, NA, 2L), A123 = c(1L, NA, 1L), B123 = c(NA, 
2L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I needed. Didn't think of pivoting longer first.

Comment: Hey @akrun, not too familiar with Regex and what I've been trying so far is throwing strange results. How would I accomplish this same thing, but if the name patterns were something like "alpha_04", "alpha_06", "beta_02, "beta_04", etc. (i.e. coalescing chunks starting with the same word).

Comment: @tmako that will be more easier i.e. `df1 %>% pivot_longer(cols = contains("_"), names_to = c("grp", ".value"), names_sep = "_")` thus the column will be `06`, `02` `04` and we also create a grouping column that have values 'alpha', 'beta'

Comment: I see, thanks a ton. So how would I coalesce from there? @akrun

Comment: @tmako you can remove the `grp` column with in across i.e. `group_by(ID) %>% summarise(across(-grp, ~ .[complete.cases(.)][1]))`

Comment: For some reason that's yielding me a dataframe with just a single row.

Comment: @tmako is it because you have all NAs in those rows

Comment: @tmako can you showe the `dput` of output `df1 %>% pivot_longer(cols = contains("_"), names_to = c("grp", ".value"), names_sep = "_")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233947/discussion-between-tmako-and-akrun).

Answer (score 1):

one more approach

```r
library(tidyverse)

split(names(df1)[-1], gsub('^\\D*(\\d+)$', '\\1', names(df1)[-1])) %>% map(~df1[c('ID', .x)]) %>%
  imap(~ .x %>% group_by(ID) %>% rowwise %>% transmute(!!.y := first(na.omit(c_across(everything())))) %>% ungroup) %>%
  reduce(left_join, by = 'ID')

#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>      ID `034` `099` `123`
#>   <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1     1     3     1
#> 2     2     2     2     2
#> 3     3     2     2     1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>