# Coalescing multiple columns from both the left and right side

Tags: r, tidyverse

Given the following data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, alpha_1 = c(2L, 2L, 3L), 
alpha_2 = c(1L, 2L,
3L), alpha_3 = c(4L, 4L, 2L), alpha_4 = c(3L, NA, NA), beta_1 = c(NA,
2L, NA), beta_2 = c(3L, NA, 2L), charlie_1 = c(1L, NA, 1L), charlie_2 = c(NA,
2L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

I'm trying to coalesce all columns sharing the same initial prefix name (i.e. coalesce alpha_1, alpha_2, alpha_3, alpha_4, and coalesce beta_1 beta_2, etc.), but from both the left and right sides. That is, I want to generate two new variables, say 'alpha_left' and 'alpha_right', whose columns would be, in this example, (2, 2, 3) and (3, 4, 2) respectively (first non-missing elements from the left and right side of the dataframe).

User @akrun offered a great solution for the coalescing part [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67992781/coalescing-multiple-chunks-of-columns-with-the-same-suffix-in-names-r), but I'm unsure how to create two new variables from both the left and right coalesces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an option in [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org/)

1. Reshape to 'long' format - [`pivot_longer`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html)
2. Grouped by 'ID'
3. Do the `summarise` `across` the columns 'alpha' till 'charlie'
4. Get the column name - `cur_column()`
5. Create a `tibble` with the first non-NA element from the `left` and the `right`
6. Change the column names by appending the 'nm1' as prefix
7. Finally, `unnest` the `list` columns created in `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = contains("_"), 
         names_to = c( ".value", "grp"), names_sep = "_") %>% 
      group_by(ID) %>%
      summarise(across(alpha:charlie, ~ {
          nm1 <- cur_column()
        tbl1 <- tibble(left= .[complete.cases(.)][1], 
                     right = rev(.)[complete.cases(rev(.))][1]);
        names(tbl1) <- str_c(nm1, "_", names(tbl1))
        list(tbl1)})) %>%
     unnest(c(alpha, beta, charlie))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 7
     ID alpha_left alpha_right beta_left beta_right charlie_left charlie_right
  <int>      <int>       <int>     <int>      <int>        <int>         <int>
1     1          2           3         3          3            1             1
2     2          2           4         2          2            2             2
3     3          3           2         2          2            1             1
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
lst1 <- lapply(split.default(df1[-1], sub("_\\d+$", "", names(df1)[-1])), 
         function(x) {
        x1 <- apply(x, 1, function(y) {
                     y1 <- na.omit(y)
         if(length(y1) > 1 ) y1[c(1, length(y1))] else y1[1]
           })
       if(is.vector(x1)) as.data.frame(matrix(x1)) else as.data.frame(t(x1)) 
})
```

Comment: Using the base R solution (much faster), how would you bind that list to the dataframe to resemble the other solution? @akrun

Comment: @tmako You can use `do.call(cbind, lst1)`  I didn't do that step because was not sure whether you need unique case (as in the base R i added `if/else`)

Answer (score 3):

You could also do:

```
df1[-1] %>%
  split.default(sub("_\\d+", "", names(.))) %>%
  imap_dfc(~data.frame(right = coalesce(!!!.x),
                       left = coalesce(!!!rev(.x))) %>%
            set_names(paste(.y, names(.), sep="_")))

  alpha_right alpha_left beta_right beta_left charlie_right charlie_left
1           2          3          3         3             1            1
2           2          4          2         2             2            2
3           3          2          2         2             1            1
```

Answer (score 2):

One more approach not as elegant as [@Onyambu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68042483/2884859)'s

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1[-1] %>%
  split.default(sub("_\\d+", "", names(.))) %>%
  imap_dfc(~ .x %>% rowwise() %>%
            mutate(!!paste0(.y, '_left') := head(na.omit(c_across(everything())),1), 
                   !!paste0(.y, '_right') := tail(na.omit(c_across(!last_col())),1),
                   .keep = 'none' )
            )
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   alpha_left alpha_right beta_left beta_right charlie_left charlie_right
#>        <int>       <int>     <int>      <int>        <int>         <int>
#> 1          2           3         3          3            1             1
#> 2          2           4         2          2            2             2
#> 3          3           2         2          2            1             1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Another option

```r
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, alpha_1 = c(2L, 2L, 3L), 
                      alpha_2 = c(1L, 2L,
                                  3L), alpha_3 = c(4L, 4L, 2L), alpha_4 = c(3L, NA, NA), beta_1 = c(NA,
                                                                                                    2L, NA), beta_2 = c(3L, NA, 2L), charlie_1 = c(1L, NA, 1L), charlie_2 = c(NA,
                                                                                                                                                                              2L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID, names_sep = "_", names_to = c(".value", "set")) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  fill(alpha:charlie, .direction = "updown") %>% 
  filter(set %in% range(set)) %>% 
  mutate(set = c("left", "right")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = ID, names_from = set, values_from = alpha:charlie)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 7
#> # Groups:   ID [3]
#>      ID alpha_left alpha_right beta_left beta_right charlie_left charlie_right
#>   <int>      <int>       <int>     <int>      <int>        <int>         <int>
#> 1     1          2           3         3          3            1             1
#> 2     2          2           4         2          2            2             2
#> 3     3          3           2         2          2            1             1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>